# How to reconcile StreamBuilder for authorization and FutureBuilder for data from api plus listview filtering

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

First of all, I'm new in a flutter and I can make a basic mistakes.

Initial assumptions:

- using flutter with firebase authentication
- using own api for additional data
- api endpoint return more data when application send user token from firebase authentication in header

My main class:

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => GoogleSignInProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: child: MyList()
    );
  }
```

And the MyList class (I simplify this class for this example):

```
class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  MyList();

  @override
  _MyListState createState() => _MyListState();
}

class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  late Future<List<Details>> _detailsList;

  Future<List<Details>> getDetailsList() async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {};
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null){
      headers["tokenID"] = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
    }

    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('http://hostname/api/v1/details/list'), headers: headers);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Details> details = [];
    for (Map details in responseJson["details"]) {
      details.add(Details.fromJson(details));
    }
    return details;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _details = getDetailsList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return FutureBuilder(
              future: _details,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Details>> snapshot) {
                return new Scaffold(
                  body: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new TextField(
                        controller: controller,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
                        onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
                      ),
                      new Expanded(
                        child: _searchResult.length != 0 ||
                            controller.text.isNotEmpty
                            ? new ListView.builder(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 50),
                          itemCount: _searchResult.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                            return new ListItem(_searchResult[i]);
                          },
                        )
                            : new ListView.builder(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return new ListItem(snapshot.data![index]);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
          );
        }

    );
  }

  List<Details> _searchResult = [];
  onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    _searchResult.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    _details.forEach((userDetail) {
      if (userDetail.name.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()))
        _searchResult.add(userDetail);
    });

    setState(() {});
  }
```

In this case, filtering/search work fine. But each typed character executes setState and reinitiation widget what causes send a request for API for every type -  I do not want such behavior.

On the other hand, I want get a new API request when user sign-in or sign-out.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the first part of the question:
To prevent setState for every typed character, you need to implement debounce and throttling for your TextField. There are many tutorials for this for sure.

Answer to the second part:
Take the firebase auth stream, do the asyncMap on the stream where you do the request every time you need based on the auth object. The stream after asyncMap will return the List and will be updated every time the auth stream updates.

Comment: The Stream<List<Details>> can then be used in the StreamBuilder.

Comment: actually `setState` should not be used here as everything can be done with `StreamBuilder` and  [Stream.debounce](https://pub.dev/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/RateLimit/debounce.html) (or similar method from `rxdart` package)

Comment: Thanks for answers. I will try this way.
@xbalaj maybe do you have any example code for to second part?